# Use 'IF EXIST' command with '<' operator

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I use a `.cmd` file (under Windows 7) to move large numbers of scanned PDF files from a 'quarantine' folder to their eventual locations.

The PDFs have file names running from `TA500xxxx.PDF` to `TA517xxxx.PDF` (where xxxx is anything from 0001 to 9999). I would like to be able to identify all the files with file names lower than `TA517xxxx.pdf` (i.e. all those from `TA5000001.pdf` to `TA5169999.pdf`) in a single operation, if possible, but IF EXIST doesn't seem to take the '<' operator, i.e. 'IF EXIST < TA517*.pdf GOTO....' doesn't work.

I could use a separate IF EXIST statement per file name block (TA500, TA501, etc.) but that seems excessive. Is there a tidy way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if the IF statement reads/accpets data from stdin at all. I don’t think so and I’ve never seen this before.

I would do something like this:

```
FOR /L %i IN (500,1,516) DO MOVE TA%i*.pdf target
```

This loop will move every PDF file from TA500* to TA516* to *target*.

Note: FOR strips leading zeroes form numbers, so sometimes you have to be very creative when doing tasks like this.

Comment: There are some possible issues. For example, the command will move files named `TA500.pdf` or `TA516abcd.pdf` even if they shouldn't be touched at all. As-is, the command will also try to move non-existent files.

Answer (score 0):

`<` and `>`  are input/output [redirection operators](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) in batch scripts, and you can't use them to compare numeric values.

The `if` command provides the following three-letter comparison operators:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

Here's an example script that should get you started:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM initialize a patter which matches any .pdf files whose
REM name begins with "TA5" and is followed by 6 characters
set pattern=TA5??????.pdf

REM get all files matching the pattern
REM in the current folder and all subfolders
for /r %%A in ("%pattern%") do (

REM retrieve the current file name
set name=%%~nA

REM get 6 characters from the original name starting from the 4th
set value=!name:~3,6!

REM ensure the value is a valid number through a regular expression
echo "!value!"|findstr "^\"[0-9]*\"$" >nul
if !errorlevel! == 0 (

REM check if the value is smaller than 170000
if !value! leq 169999 (
echo %%A
)))

pause >nul
endlocal & exit /b
```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)